# How can I define variables in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

**This code:**

```
string[] files = {"test.txt", 
    "test2.txt", 
    "notes.txt", 
    "notes.doc", 
    "data.xml", 
    "test.xml", 
    "test.html", 
    "notes.txt", 
    "test.as"};

files.ToList().ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(
        f.Substring(
            f.IndexOf('.') + 1, 
            f.Length - f.IndexOf('.') - 1
            )
    ));
```

**produces this list:**

```
txt
txt
txt
doc
xml
xml
html
txt
as
```

**Is there some way to make `f.IndexOf('.')` a variable** so that in more complex LINQ queries I have this defined in one place?

Comment: As Greg Beech says, this is not LINQ. The example code is using a Lambda function. They have some overlap in functionality, but they're not the same things.

Comment: And, in this concrete example, you could use the Substring overload which accepts only the substring start index (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28VS.80%29.aspx) and returns the rest of the string.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you were using Linq then you could use the `let` keyword to define an inline variable (the code posted in the question isn't actually using Linq).

```
var ext = from file in files
          let idx = f.LastIndexOf('.') + 1
          select file.Substring(idx);
```

However for the specific scenario you've posted I'd recommend using `Path.GetExtension` instead of parsing the string yourself (for example, your code will break if any of the files have a `.` in the file name).

```
var ext = from file in files select Path.GetExtension(file).TrimStart('.');
foreach (var e in ext)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `let idx = file.LastIndexOf` ? 'f' is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

You could do this

```
files.ToList().ForEach(f => { var i = f.IndexOf('.'); 
   Console.WriteLine(f.Substring(i + 1, f.Length - i - 1));}
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the `from` kind of syntax, you can do something similar with the `Select` method:

```
var extensions = files
        .Select(x => new { Name = x, Dot = x.IndexOf('.') + 1 })
        .Select(x => x.Name.Substring(x.Dot));
```

Although, like Greg, I would recommend using the `Path.GetExtension` method. And with methods, that could like like this:

```
var extensions = files
        .Select(x => Path.GetExtension(x));
```

And in this case I really think that is a lot easier to read than the suggested linq statements.

---

To write it to the console, you can do this:

```
extensions
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```